# Spring Boot Integration Test for Service method annotated with @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions, spring-test

I'm using Spring Boot and trying to write an integration test in which a method annotated: `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` is called.

My test method is annotated:

```
@Test
@Transactional
@Sql(scripts = {
        "/sql/insert_some_records.sql"
}, executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)
```

With this configuration I'm getting a strange behaviour and when I tried to debug I found out that the service bean class method I'm trying to test can't find the records I've inserted using the sql script in the `@Sql` i.e.
`myRepo.findAll()` inside the method gets an empty list.

I've managed to run the test after changing the propagation option for the **test method** to:

`@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)`

or:

`@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)`

And the method in the service class can correctly find all records from DB, but the drawback is that I have to manually delete these inserted records by the script after the test.

I've read Spring documentation about Propagation option and still really confused.

Can anyone explain for me what's the cause of the problem? And why everything works after changing the propagation option?

Comment: Have you read the corresponding documentation yet?

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-tx

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#tx-propagation

Comment: Yes, I've read it, but I can't understand particularly why I see this behavior in my tests.

Answer (score 1):

when test run, it create a transaction T1 by default if with annotation @Trasactional, and your service method create another transaction T2 per REQUIRE_NEW, since T1 has not commit util test over, T2 can not see the data that has not been committed. but if test is without  @Transactional , or NEVER or SUPPORT, it will not create a transaction, but the sql was execute by jdbcTemplate.execute(), it will create a T1 and commit immediately after execute() return. so service method is able to see the data.